# Notification with Ignore button opens up the Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-notifications, android-pendingintent

I have notifications in my app being fired after certain periods of time using AlarmManager.
The notification ahs two buttons, one performs some writing to database, the other is Ignore button, which just removes the notification. But the problem is, it opens up the activity of the app, which isnt supposed to happen, why is that?
Here is how the notification is being set up

```
public static void sendNotification(Context context) {
    NotificationManager mNotifyManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
    mBuilder.setContentTitle("My LeApp")
            .setContentText("New event!")
            .setContentIntent(getPendingIntent(context, 0, ActivityStage2.class))
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notif_icon)
            .addAction(R.drawable.notif_take, "Take", getPendingIntent(context, 1, Take.class))
            .addAction(R.drawable.notif_ignore, "Ignore", getPendingIntent(context, 2, Ignore.class))
            .setAutoCancel(true);
    mNotifyManager.notify(0, mBuilder.build());
```

and here is the Ignore activity

```
public class Ignore extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE != null) {
        NotificationManager nMgr = (NotificationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        nMgr.cancel(0);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: but what if I want when clicking on the notification to open the activity?

Comment: unfortunately I have suggested the wrong one..

Comment: I think you don;t want to open any activity when you click on ignore notify...Right?

Comment: noooo, its a notification with 2 separate buttons on it, the actions of those buttons are handled in Take and Ignore classes, but when clicking the notification, I think would be good to open the activity

Comment: ok..then you asked that your notification open the activity on click....now what you want ?

Comment: when clicking the Ignore button it opens the activity, which shouldnt happen

Comment: Of course it opens the `Ignore` activity. You've configured it to do exactly that. If you don't want an activity opened when the ignore button is pressed, then you should have it start a `BroadcastReceiver` as Ranjit suggested and dismiss the notification within the `BroadcastReceiver`.

Answer (score 1):

You are opening one Activity page on dismiss button click..

Not used but I can give one suggession to avoid this..

Use one `BroadcasrReceiver` instead of `Activity` and cancel the Notification inside `onReceive()` ..